# Java Swing: Making a Combo Box error message

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, combobox

I'm fairly new to Java Swing and I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a catch error for a combo box. It was fairly easy with a text box where I could simply `.getText()` and `.equals()` it to a value I wanted it to catch for, such as

```
if(!textFrame.getText().trim().equals("")){
    do Stuff
}else{
    errorMessage.setText("You need to fill that field");
}
```

How do I do this same thing, but with a combo box? Something along the lines of:

```
if(!comboBox.getScrollValue().equals("Value")){
    do Stuff
}else{
    errorMessage.setText("You need to select a thingy");
```

Comment: `getScrollValue()`? Have you looked at 1) the [JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and 2) the [JComboBox API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)? If it were me, that's where I'd start. Using these resources is a learned skill that gets better with practice, and the sooner you start practicing the better. In fact if I were to give an "official" answer to this question it would be: check out these resources before coming here. You'll gain more in the long run. Much luck!

Comment: Note, that if the user does not make a selection, the selected index is -1, and so if you wish to check if a selection has not yet been made, then perhaps this is what you really want to test: `if (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1)` then show error message.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it now. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *JComboBox.getSelectedItem()* method:

```
// use VALUE.equals(comboBox.getSelectedItem()) to avoid NullPointerException
if(!"Value".equals(comboBox.getSelectedItem())){
```

More about *JComboBox* you can read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html